# Set a BOOL right after checking it

Tags: objective-c

I'm working through someone else's codebase and there are several lines like this:

```
if (self.aBooleanProperty) {
    self.aBooleanProperty = YES;
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Is there *any* point to setting it to `YES` right after checking it? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: if self.aBooleanProperty is yes only then it goes inside the loop.

Comment: You are not missing anything.. The someone you mentioned missing plenty

Comment: When dealing with a Boolean variable there's no point in the above pattern - wasted motion.  With Objective-C properties there **is** a slight chance that the setter has some side-effect that is desired.  But most likely this pattern is just the result of repeated edits to the code -- you can fairly easily get strange stuff like this when you change this, then that, then this again.

Comment: I remember a programmer in my team writing two lines `a = nil;` `a = ...;`. When I asked him about it, he told me it makes the code more robust. He doesn't work in my team any more.

Comment: @HotLicks This is probably the reason. This codebase has been through a few programmers I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (self.aBooleanProperty) {
    self.aBooleanProperty = YES;
    // Do some stuff
}
```

In properly written code, you aren't missing anything and that setter line increases the billable lines of code by one with a no-op.

There are two reasons, though, that this could be done for misguided reasons.

As @HotLicks said, there *may* be side effects to the setter that *might* need to be triggered.  But they should have been triggered on set *unless the developer had the misguided notion of setting the ivar directly everywhere and then using the above to coalesce the cost of setting to one spot*.   But that'd be a remarkably fragile and silly thing to do.

The other reason is because, traditionally, Objective-C's BOOL is a glorified `char`.  Only it isn't so glorified.   Thus, comparing a BOOL to `YES` is actually dangerous because `YES` has an explicit value.

```
BOOL mmmmmK = 2;  // this is valid

if (mmmmmK == YES) { /* this won't execute */ }
```

Sort of like when climbing a cliff and something starts falling, you don't yell "bottle", "shoe", "pebble", or "prosthetic limb", but you always yell **ROCK**.

So, *maybe* the developer was thinking of normalizing the affirmative with an explicit YES.  Again, quite doubtful and, even if that is the case, then it should raise suspicion about the quality of the rest of the codebase.

Ouch.

Comment: This is what I was originally thinking, that the check was for it being setting to something other than `YES` or `NO`. But looking at the rest of the code, there's a lot of waste (setting `UIButton` titles to the same string for all four states, repeated code). So maybe it's just to puff up the code.

Comment: Check the original contract;  if it is billed by line of code, there's your answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to tell without having more code. I think everybody will agree the code appears to be wrong, however, what we are seeing is an obj-c property - the previous programmer could do some "clever" thing, e.g. it's possible that the getter of `aBooleanProperty` sets itself to `NO` when you call it.

Before modifying the code, check the getters. This reminds me of [schrödinbug](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96973/whats-a-schrodinbug)

Comment: No getters in the code for this property, it's fully synthesized.

Answer (score 1):

I think the person miswrote YES, instead should've written NO as it already is YES when it checked in the condition. Or otherwise there isne any point to that line.

Comment: I don't think they meant `NO`. They set `NO` at a central point in the code when everything is finished.

Answer (score 0):

if

```
 self.aBooleanProperty = YES;
```

is included in the braces,it is not needed and if it is

```
 self.aBooleanProperty = NO;
```

is included ,then it is logical